Upgrade 22.04 -> 24.04.01 fails - no network after rollback
I am attempting to upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04(.01) for months (sporadically tried 2-3 times in September, once mid October and once yesterday) and still the same issue happens: the upgrade tool passes all the steps until it should start downloading and installing new/upgraded packages, which fails due to no network available.
Luckily enough it is able to rollback all the previous steps (which includes removing plenty of applications) and I am left with no networking. Luckily, a restart is all that is needed to resolve this.
Speaking about resolving (pun intended), I have noticed that resolvconf or some stuff around dhcp is on the remove list. I suspect this is the reason why networking stops working and no new packages can be downloaded.
How to fix this? Is this expected to happen or is it a bug? How is that nobody else experience(s|d) the same issue? 24.04.01 was released end of August and I have noticed some people had issues upgrading soon after that, but they do not seem to be related to my issues and no new issues are reported since early September.
Here is some upgrader tool output:
Do you want to start the upgrade? 


2 installed packages are no longer supported by Canonical. You can 
still get support from the community. 

201 packages are going to be removed. 641 new packages are going to 
be installed. 2187 packages are going to be upgraded. 

You have to download a total of 14,6 M.

followed by a prompt to continue, cancel or show details. Showing the details of to be removed apps:
No longer supported: isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common 


Remove: gimp gimp-plugin-registry gimp-texturize libargon2-0 libatm1 
  libdb5.3 libelf1 libext2fs2 libglib2.0-0 libgnutls30 libmagic1 
  libmemcached11 libopenconnect5 network-manager-openconnect 
  network-manager-openconnect-gnome openconnect resolvconf

Many thanks for your help!

"How is that nobody else experience(s|d) the same issue?" Nobody has the same hardware nor the same network connection as you. Maybe you changed a setting. Maybe your cat changed a setting while walking across the keyboard. There are many possibilities.
